# How do I change the logging level with Firestore JS SDK to only log Errors?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It seems that there is a function available to do that according to the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore#setloglevel

```
firebase.firestore.setLogLevel('error');
```

But how do I set the setting after I initialise the firestore client? The below returns undefined

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
db.setLogLevel("error")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setLogLevel` method is a static method in `firebase.firestore`. It is **not** an instance method on `firebase.firestore()`.

So you should call the exact line you have in your first snippet (**without** `()` after `firestore`) anywhere in your code, but typically right before the call to `firebase.initializeApp`.

Comment: Thanks, this should have worked but i'm still getting all the INFO logs from every fetch. I've restarted both the react app (might need to rm cache) and the emulator